# Responsive width and height when programatically adding views

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently using a Table Layout and programatically adding rows and buttons. However, when I add the views a lot of them go off-screen. Is there a way to programatically set the size to the portion of the screen.

I have decent experience with Android, but new to Kotlin.

Here is where I add the views

```
private fun setupTable () {
    for(i in 0 until this.rowSize) {
        val row = TableRow(context)
        row.layoutParams
        row.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        for(j in 0 until this.columnSize) {
            val button = Button(context)
            button.apply {
                layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                text = "R $i C $j"
            }
            row.addView(button)
        }
        wordLayout?.addView(row)
    }
}
```

Here is the picture for reference. Here I want a 10x10 table and to fit all the buttons inside the TableLayout.

[image]

Comment: you mean you want to show 10 columns in screen without scrolling horizontal right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
package net.androidly.androidlylayouts

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val ROWS = 10
    val COLUMNS = 5
    val tableLayout by lazy { TableLayout(this) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView.text = "ROWS : $ROWS COLUMNS: $COLUMNS"

        val lp = TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        tableLayout.apply {
            layoutParams = lp
            isShrinkAllColumns = true
        }
        createTable(ROWS, COLUMNS)
    }

    fun createTable(rows: Int, cols: Int) {

        for (i in 0 until rows) {

            val row = TableRow(this)
            row.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            for (j in 0 until cols) {

                val button = Button(this)
                button.apply {
                    layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                    text = "R $i C $j"
                }
                row.addView(button)
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row)
        }
        linearLayout.addView(tableLayout)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

[image]